# C# : Replace text from < char until > char

Tags: c#

So I am trying to replace all text from < chat until > char because of colors tags and etc...

I just tried this code:

```
while (text.Contains("<") || text.Contains(">"))
{
    text = text.Remove(text.IndexOf("<"), text.IndexOf(">"));
}
```

And somewhy this code won't work.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Read the documentation. I think the second parameter is length to remove and not last index.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - and also give more context for what you're trying to do. If you're dealing with XML, using an XML API is almost certainly a better option.

Answer (score 1):

The function `Remove` takes two arguments **startIndex** and **count**. Where **count** is the number of characters to remove.

```
public string Remove(
    int startIndex,
    int count
)
```

You need to calculate the distance from `<` to `>`, and use that distance as the second argument for `Remove`. The code should look something like this:

```
while (text.Contains("<") || text.Contains(">"))
{
    var start = text.IndexOf("<");
    var end = text.IndexOf(">") + 1;
    var dist = end - start;
    text = text.Remove(start, dist);
}
```

**NOTE:** You should add some additional checks making sure that `<` and `>` occurs in the expected order, and that they occur the same number of times.

Comment: int wheretostop = text.IndexOf(">") - text.IndexOf("<");
text = text.Remove(text.IndexOf("<"), wheretostop);

Comment: What does not work? Provide a input and the expected output.

Comment: Getting the input for you

Comment: <color=#ff6600>[Console] save</color>

Comment: This is the input

Comment: Trying to remove all tags from text like <color> tag

Comment: I have updated the code. You should have been able to solve this by a little debugging.

Comment: This is what I am just trying now, Kek. I'll try and see now